# Runtime method to get names of argument variables?

Tags: objective-c

Inside an Objective-C method, it is possible to get the selector of the method with the keyword `_cmd`. Does such a thing exist for the names of arguments?

For example, if I have a method declared as such:

```
- (void)methodWithAnArgument:(id)foo {
  ...
}
```

Is there some sort of construct that would allow me to get access to some sort of string-like representation of the variable name? That is, not the *value* of foo, but something that actually reflects the *variable name* "foo" in a local variable inside the method.

This information doesn't appear to be stored in `NSInvocation` or any of its related classes (`NSMethodSignature`, etc), so I'm not optimistic this can be done using Apple's frameworks or the runtime. I suspect it might be possible with some sort of compile-time macro, but I'm unfamiliar with C macros so I wouldn't know where to begin.

---

*Edit to contain more information about what I'm actually trying to do.*

I'm building a tool to help make working with third-party URL schemes easier. There are two sides to how I want my API to look:

As a consumer of a URL scheme, I can call a method like `[twitterHandler showUserWithScreenName:@"someTwitterHandle"];`

As a creator of an app with a URL scheme, I can define my URLs in a plist dictionary, whose key-value pairs look something like `@"showUserWithScreenName": @"twitter://user?screenName={screenName}"`.

What I'm working on now is finding the best way to glue these together. The current fully-functioning implementation of `showUserWithScreenName:` looks something like this:

```
- (void)showUserWithScreenName:(NSString *)screenName {
    [self performCommand:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) withArguments:@{@"screenName": screenName}];
}
```

Where `performCommand:withArguments:` is a method that (besides some other logic) looks up the command key in the plist (in this case "showUserWithScreenName:") and evaluates the value as a template using the passed dictionary as the values to bind.

The problem I'm trying to solve: there are dozens of methods like this that look exactly the same, but just swap out the dictionary definition to contain the correct template params. In every case, the desired dictionary key is the name of the parameter. I'm trying to find a way to minimize my boilerplate.

In practice, I assume I'm going to accept that there will be some boilerplate needed, but I can probably make it ever-so-slightly cleaner thanks to `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` (thanks @CodaFi — I wasn't familiar with that macro!). For the sake of argument, I'm curious if it would be possible to completely metaprogram this using something like `forwardInvocation:`, which as far as I can tell would require some way to access parameter names.

Comment: No.  Names get compiled to addresses and offsets, so the only way to keep them around would be an `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings()` type construct.

Comment: Nope, not possible. What are you trying to do? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @RedAlert That's almost right, except that two out of your two assertions are wrong (neither is Objective-C a low-level language, nor do method names vanish with compilation.)

Comment: As "Berg" asked, what is your goal? Mentioning that in your question might allow someone to offer a solution to meet your needs.

Comment: I updated the original question with a fair bit more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByString:` with a `:` after you get the string from `NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)` and use your `@selector`'s argument names to put the arguments in the correct order.

You can also take a look at this [post](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/method-names-in-objective-c.html), which is describing the method naming conventions in Objective C

Comment: I suppose that would work, but it requires an even stricter set of restrictions on method names than standard Obj-C naming conventions. Take a method like UITableView's `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Splitting on `:` gives you "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" and "forIndexPath", neither of which is a proper argument name. In many cases you can then split again on uppercase characters; that could work for "Identifier", but would fail on "IndexPath".

Then again, enforcing stricter naming conventions for my use case (namely, no multi-word argument names) might be okay.

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to use that solution for generic stuff. Also you might have to add some build scripts to your project to parse the methods and the plist so you can get a warning if there is inconsistency between the contents of the plist and your method names, otherwise it's going to be extremely unsafe.